# imagen fondo wordpress

Tags: imagen, background

lanzo una consulta a ver si me podéis ayudar
. Estoy haciendo una página web con wordpress y estoy intentando meter un fondo con unas lineas laterales de colores, es decir todo el fondo es blanco y a los laterales hay como unas pequeñas líneas, el fondo está aqui: https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50115893367_4593b8a1f1_k.jpg

Para que me lo "pinte" así el código es el siguiente:

```
body{
  width:100%;
  background-image: url(https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50115893367_4593b8a1f1_k.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PEro de esta manera tanto en la cabecera como en la parte derecha del footer se pierde este fondo y no salen las lineas

Si lo pongo así:

```
 .container{
  width:100%;
  background-image: url(https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50115893367_4593b8a1f1_k.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Me sale de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es: COMO HAGO PARA QUE SE VEA ESE FONDO EN TODA LA PÁGINA CON LAS LINEAS EN EL EXTREMO DE LA PÁGINA? Tanto en cabecera como en cuerpo y pie de página sin saltos raros

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: El background debe de ir al Body para hacer lo que quieres. Con la primera parte de código debería de funcionar. Respecto al encabezado y el footer, probablemente es porque tienen un background blanco que se pone sobre el background del body. Prueba a usar la herramiento de inspección de google para ver si el header/footer tiene un fondo puesto. Si lo tienes en producción puedo echarle un vistaso si quieres.

Comment: hola Charlie , primero de todo muchas gracias. Mira la web está aquí     http://eitk.atwebpages.com/    ,    he conseguido desde body que la imagen de fondo esté tanto en el cuerpo como en el footer pero sigo en la cabecera sin poder solucionarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo aquí el código CSS ha añadir para solucionar el problema.

```
.main-header {
    background: transparent !important;
}
.top-bar-area {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

El problema es que ambos tenían fondos de color blanco. Con eso los pones transparentes para que se pueda ver la imagen de fondo.

Comment: Charlie muchísimas muchísimas muchísimas  gracias!!!!!!!